# Checking function calls are not passed as arguments (C macros)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In a project I work on we have some utility macros which reference their argument more then once.

Lets use a simple example:

```
#define ABS(a)  ( (a) < 0 ? (-(a)) : (a) )
```

Now this is a large code base, and while we do review code, every now and then I find a function call  being passed to a macro.
This isn't an **error**, but it means the function call is made multiple times which I normally don't want.

In this case we can replace with `fabsf`, `fabs`, `abs` for `float`/`double`/`int` at least, but let's assume there isn't always a good built-in replacement and the macro will stay a macro.

Example:

```
f = ABS(dot_v3v3(vel, sp));

/* expands into */
f = ( ( dot_v3v3(vel, sp) ) < 0 ? (-( dot_v3v3(vel, sp) )) : ( dot_v3v3(vel, sp) ) );
```

So my question is:

Can function calls used inside a macro be detected (either as warnings or errors)?

---

### Partial solution:

*Here are some things I already checked on...*

#### Comparing Pointers

This will cause function calls not to compile, but has the drawback that constants like '1' also give errors as well as expressions like (b - c).

```
#define ABS(a)  ((void)((&a) == (&a)), ( (a) < 0 ? (-(a)) : (a) ))
```

*Note: I found this already quite handy to point out SOME bad macro use, but since it has false-positives, it cant be left in.*

#### C11 Generics

Using `_Generic`, you can turn C macros into wrappers for inline functions. This means the problem of a function call being invoked multiple times in a macro goes away.

```
#define ABS(a) \
    _Generic((a), \
        long double: my_abs_double(a), \
        float: my_abs_float(a), \
        int:  my_abs_int(a) \
        /* ... and so on, char, long, short... etc */ \
        )
```

This isn't a workable solution yet — we still support compilers which don't support generics.

Comment: Must you also support compilers without inline functions?

Comment: We support compilers with inline functions - yes, so I guess the answer I will get is **"Dont use macros"**.

Comment: Pretty much the answer here is don't use expressions in a macro more than once.  If your macro exists in a void context (e.g. calls a function with no return) then you can get away with wrapping your macro in a `do { } while (0)` block and assigning your expression to a local variable.  But none of your examples allow for that.

Comment: @Ben Reser, sure - but **Dont do it** is advice - not an assurance, at this point I had to manually check for instances when it happens, I was curious if there was some more reliable way to check for this case - seems not simply at least (I guess you could somehow count function calls, run through the preprocessor and count again) -- but this is fairly heavy solution.

Comment: Cannot you use inside the macro something like:#define ABS(a)  ( UNIQUE_NAME=(a); UNIQUE_NAME < 0 ? (-UNIQUE_NAME) : UNIQUE_NAME )

Comment: @axeoth this issue with this `UNIQUE_NAME` must be declared outside the macro which makes using the macro rather awkward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did find this trick in the [MirOS C Preprocessor manual in the section on duplicating side effects](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/manINFO/cpp.html#Macro-Pitfalls):

```
 #define min(X, Y)                \
 ({ typeof (X) x_ = (X);          \
    typeof (Y) y_ = (Y);          \
    (x_ < y_) ? x_ : y_; })
```

Comment: This will work around the problem, but note that it relies on two gcc extensions (Those extensions are supported by clang and icc too though)

Comment: Even though this uses gcc/icc/clang extensions, this probably the closest thing there is to an answer.

Comment: Yeah... This also deals with the case of incr / decr like MIN(i--,j++)